# Ajax request with list of javascript objects failing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This question is asked a lot, but none of the answers worked for me. I'm trying to send a list of objects to a controller in ASP MVC 5. I'm `JOSN.stringify`'ing the list, and trying to receive it into a list.

I sure hope it's not some stupid typo I'm missing...

*Well* I did just find a typo (funny how writing things down helps), but it isn't the problem. The ajax is calling "Sale" but the controller is "Sales". I fixed it, but still same problem. (added picture at end).

**Edit**

I changed the ajax to:

```
$('#complete-sale').on('click', function ()
{
    alert("in complete sale");
    var itemsInCart = JSON.stringify(shoppingCart.getItemsInCart());
    alert("itemsInCart: " + itemsInCart);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Sales/completeSale", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { 'itemsInCart': itemsInCart },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("sale complete succeeded" + result[0]);
            addItemToCart(result[0]);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("failed complete sale request " + result[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

The request URL shown in developer tools is now:

```
http://localhost:52459/Sales/completeSale?itemsInCart=[{"ItemId":1,"Quantity":"1","Price":3.5}]
```

Which seems like it should be right. I also changed the controller return to `return View("hello")` so something actually comes back.

Model:

```
public class ItemInCart
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Variety variety { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual InventoryItem inventoryItem { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Variety price { get; set; }

}
```

Controller (`Sales.cs`):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult completeSale(List<ItemInCart> itemsInCart)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Ajax:

```
$('#complete-sale').on('click', function ()
{
    alert("in complete sale");
    itemsInCart = shoppingCart.getItemsInCart();
    stringifiedItemsInCart = JSON.stringify({ 'itemsInCart': itemsInCart});
    alert("stringified: " + stringifiedItemsInCart);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/SalescompleteSale", // the method we are calling
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: stringifiedItemsInCart,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("sale complete succeeded" + result[0]);
            addItemToCart(result[0]);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("failded complete sale request " + result[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

[image: alert request failed]

[image: ajax post stringified]

[image: developer tools 1]

[image: developer tools 2]

[image]

Comment: You should be posting this instead.

Comment: You are doing an Ajax GET request, it should be a POST from the looks of your code.

Comment: @jumpingcode Why is that? My other similar GET requests are working fine--they are just not lists.

Comment: If your method is going to be making database changes, it should be a POST

Comment: Ok, and it is going to make changes, and the other GET requests are just gathering information. But, in principle, the request should still go through, right? The controller is currently empty. I'll try it as POST.

Comment: POST didn't work. I also added `return View("hello")` to make sure I was returning *something

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem the other day, and it can be a little confusing, especially in your case where you are the method signature involves a list of a view models.

`JSON.stringify()` seems to always work great for me with `POST` data and maybe someone else can explain why that is, but with `GET` requests, it is not the right solution.

The problem I had was with requesting a URL with list of `int`, and like you it was either coming up as `null` or erroring. What I actually needed to do was create a query string as such: `?selectedIds=1&selectedIds=2&selectedIds=3`.

Comment: But as you can see, I'm not sending a list of ints.  The URL is `http://localhost:52459/Sales/completeSale?{"itemsInCart":[{"ItemId":1,"Quantity":"1","Price":3.5}]}`. Although, now that I'm looking at that, maybe that isn't quite right. It should probably be `...?itemsInCart=[{...}]`.

Comment: I can post the answer later, but you should really be able to figure it out yourself now

Comment: I think I've got the URL request ok now (see question edit). The thing is, I'm kind of a beginner. I was able to figure out how to make my ajax requests work with a single object, but just not a list of objects.